# Oracle PL/SQL RefCursor local collection type

Tags: oracle

I need to run some XML indoc statements in PL/SQL and then return the result as a ref cursor. Now, I can have multiple rows here, which I collects into the PL/SQL Collection, but to return the refcursor for this collection, the collection must be defined at the SQL Level (not pl/sql local collection type). I cannot create the object types as needed outside of my pl/sql. Is there a way, I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your collection object in block and save the statements in that collection . Then return that colletion object as an argument to PL/SQL function and in that function set the cursor to start index of the collection object.
**The Function should take Collection as an argument and return curstor.**